# Prove that a set is a subset using element method of proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$(A\cup B)-(B\cap C) \subseteq(A-B)\cup(B-C)$

Suppose $x \in(A\cup B)-(B\cap C)$, then

$(x\in A \lor x\in B) \land (x\notin B \lor x\notin C) \equiv$

$\equiv\bigl((x\in A \lor x\in B)\land x\notin B\bigr)\lor\bigl((x\in A \lor x\in B)\land x\notin C\bigr)\equiv$

$\equiv\bigl((x\notin B \land x\in A) \lor (x\notin B \land x\in B) \bigr)\lor\bigl((x\notin C \land x\in A) \lor (x\notin C \land x\in B) \bigr)$

Consider the following cases:

1. $(x\notin B \land x\in A) \iff x\in A-B \therefore x \in (A-B)\cup(B-C)$
2. $(x\notin B \land x\in B)$, that's not possible
3. $(x\notin C \land x\in A)$, not sure how to deduce that $x \in (A-B)\cup(B-C)$
4. $(x\notin C \land x\in B) \iff x \in B - C \therefore x \in (A-B)\cup(B-C)$

Have I divided the proof into cases correctly? If so, how to finish the case #3?

Comment: you mean $x\notin B $ or $x\notin A$

Comment: sorry, typo, fixed

Comment: 3) can be split into two cases: 3a)($x\not \in C\land x\in A)\land x \not \in B$ then $x \in (A-B)$.  and 3b) $(x\not \in C\land x\in A)\land x \in B$ then $x \in(B-C)$.

Comment: It looks correct. For case 3, split into two subcases, depending on whether $x\in B$ or not. Indeed, I think the entire proof happens to become much easier if you start by splitting into the cases $x\in B$ and $x\notin B$.